# Committing trivial changes by regexp with git

Tags: git

I am trying to clean up a commit history to make it more understandable.

Due to a change in style guideline, commits may contain many changes that are nothing more than removing lines containing nothing but an empty comment, optionally replacing it with an empty line. Many diff entries will therefore be quite obscured, e.g.

```
--- a/src/somefile
+++ b/src/somefile
@@ <some header>
-   #
-   #
-   #
+
    SOME(STUFF THAT HASNT CHANGED) {
-       #
-       #
+
+       THE ONE LINE THAT ACTUALLY IS RELEVANT
    END
-   #
-   #
-   #
```

This makes the code-review process more difficult than I'd like, so I checked out the changes and created a reviewing branch and try to separate the commit into several smaller commits, separating semantic changes from formatting-only changes.

With `git gui` I can do this by hand. But this problem affects a large number of lines of code, so I would like to automate this.

The only option I am aware of is to create a patch with `git diff -G<REGEXP>`, but that regexp is matched against chunks, not lines. The same issue applies with `grepdiff`. I couldn't find any tool that would allow editing a patch file in such a manner that changes can be picked line-by-line.

Is there some way I could automatically commit the trivial `-   #` and `+` 
 changes only?

Comment: `git add -p`, `git rebase -i`

Comment: @MadPhysicist Git add `-p` is manual, not automated based on a regexp. That's what I am doing currently and want to avoid. It also operates on "by hunk" basis, which again mixes trivial and relevant changes.

Comment: You can edit individual lines with `-p`

Comment: @MadPhysicist But I can't easily automate it. Manually, it is easiert with `git gui`.

Comment: *...commits may contain many changes that are nothing more than...* Guidelines like these suck.

Comment: 0andriy. To be fair, I think that OP meant "might", not "may" :)