# grepdiff: Find hunks that DON'T match a given regexp?

Tags: git, grep, diff

Related to [Committing trivial changes by regexp with git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57628288/committing-trivial-changes-by-regexp-with-git):

Using `git diff -U0` and `grepdiff --output-matching=hunk`, is there any way to obtain only hunks that *don't* match the given regexp?

I am trying to produce a patch, that applies all "trivial" changes, that is changes that only add or remove lines that

- are empty, or
- contain nothing but a comment character (`!` in this case).

It seems that `grepdiff` can only find changes that match the regexp, but not the reverse, and there seems to be no way to say "the whole hunk must match the regexp" -- if any one line matches, the hunk is considered a match.

Comment: `grepdiff` sounds like a really cool tool. I wish I could install it on my Windows machine!

Comment: I opened https://github.com/twaugh/patchutils/issues/36

Comment: Issue still opened :s